# Dynamitey exception when accessing input DocumentDB with F# in Azure Functions

Tags: azure, f#, azure-cosmosdb, azure-functions

I have an issue when using a DocumentDB input binding in Azure Functions with F#. When trying to access the dynamic object, I'm getting this error message:

> Exception while executing function: Functions.myFunctionName. mscorlib: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. FSharp.Interop.Dynamic: Could not load file or assembly 'Dynamitey, Version=1.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cbf53ea3aeb972c6' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I've done as specified in https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/functions-bindings-documentdb/ with Dynamitey and Dynamic in package references. The error only occurs when trying to access a field, like
`document?text <- "New value"`
. I've also verified that the document object is not null.
Has anyone done this successfully?

```
open FSharp.Interop.Dynamic
let Run(inputqueue: EventItem, document: obj, log: TraceWriter) =
    match document with
    | null -> 
        log.Info(sprintf "No document found") 
    | _ ->
        log.Info(sprintf "Document found")
        document?text <- "New value"


project.json file:
{
    "frameworks": {
        "net46": {
            "dependencies": {
                "FSharp.Data": "2.3.2",
                "Newtonsoft.Json": "9.0.1",
                "Dynamitey": "1.0.2",
                "FSharp.Interop.Dynamic": "3.0.0"
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your project.json file?

Comment: Added project.json to the post now.

Comment: I was able to repro this.
I'll further investigate this and will update this question when fixed. In the meantime, as a workaround, you can try to move that assembly to a bin folder (in your function folder) and reference it using a #r "Dynamitey" (removing from project.json)

Comment: Thanks. Tried the bin folder workaround, but it failed with the same error message. Noticed that FSharp.Interop.Dynamic was still adding Dynamitey  as a dependency. Tried to remove FSharp.Interop.Dynamic from packages.json and moved the dll to bin with a #r reference. Got a new error - The type initializer for 'Dynamitey.Dynamic' threw an exception. mscorlib: Could not load file or assembly 'ImpromptuInterface, The parameter is incorrect.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I created a bin folder and added:   #r "../bin/Dynamitey.dll"
#r "../bin/FSharp.Interop.Dynamic.dll"   to load the libraries manually. The issue only happened when I tried to access dynamic content.